# need iptables rule to accept all incoming traffic

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

For my test environment i want to accept all incoming traffic, can someone please give me the iptable rule to be added.

My current *iptables -L -n* output looks like this

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>   state RELATED,ESTABLISHED ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0
>   0.0.0.0/0 ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
>   REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>   reject-with icmp-host-prohibited ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0
>   0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8443 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:9443 ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:2124
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
>   reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source
>   destination

Thanks

Answer (score 83):

Run the following. It'll insert the rule at the top of your iptables and will allow all traffic unless subsequently handled by another rule.

```bash
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
```

You can also flush your entire iptables setup with the following:

```bash
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t raw -X
iptables -t security -F
iptables -t security -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

If you flush it, you might want to run something like:

```bash
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow all loopback traffic"
iptables -A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT -m comment --comment "Drop all traffic to 127 that doesn't use lo"
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept all outgoing"
iptables -A INPUT -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept all incoming"
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow all incoming on established connections"
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT -m comment --comment "Reject all incoming"
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT -m comment --comment "Reject all forwarded"
```

If you want to be a bit safer with your traffic, don't use the accept all incoming rule, or remove it with "iptables -D INPUT -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Accept all incoming"", and add more specific rules like:

```bash
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow HTTP"
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow HTTPS"
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow SSH"
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8071:8079 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment "Allow torrents"
```

NOTE: They need to be above the 2 reject rules at the bottom, so use I to insert them at the top. Or if you're anal like me, use "iptables -nL --line-numbers" to get the line numbers, then use "iptables -I INPUT  ..." to insert a rule at a specific line number.

Finally, save your work with:

```bash
iptables-save > /etc/network/iptables.rules #Or wherever your iptables.rules file is
```

Comment: This answer finally ended my pain.  This answer addresses the question "how do I just make #@$#% iptables do what I want it to do and only what I want it to do"  The only improvement I would recommend is adding an example of forwarding a port. (ie, from 80 to 8080 and 443 to 8443)  I think 99% of the questions about iptables would be answered in 1 single post.

Comment: A bit late getting back to this, but here it is. Redirecting traffic from one port to another: "iptables -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080". It's easy enough to adjust it to do whatever you want. The only requirement is that *both* ports must be open (via entries above this statement.)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 24):

to accept all incoming traffic you can use following command , -P is to set default policy as accept

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

if you do not require your previous rules just flush/remove  them and then use above command.
to flush all rules use

```
iptables -F
```