# Allow only one website using iptables in a linux router

Tags: linux, router, iptables, gateway

I have a Linux server I'm using as a router for my internal network. I need to block all the websites except one or two using iptables.

How can I set this up?

Comment: A proxy would be better...?

Comment: try with deny policies and this iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string --string "allowed-site.com" --algo kmp -j ACCEPT and as @BigChris sayd, try with a proxy

Comment: this line might do it too , if you are doing it by IP `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 5.6.7.8 -j ACCEPT`   and whether you go by IP or domain or both. Add to that `iptables -P INPUT -j DROP` and 
`iptables -P OUTPUT -j DROP` and 
`iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT`   I may have missed something though as I don't use iptables much

Comment: [This article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-block-an-ip-on-my-linux-server/) may help point you in the right direction.

Comment: A proxy is not an option because the problems with the ssl encryption on transparent mode. I need to use the 80 and 443 ports because is an aplication which need to reach the internet.

Comment: Also, from the server i need to reach the internet, which the chain Output is  not an option. Also i already try using this: [code](iptables -P FORWARD DROP) [code](iptables -A forward -p tcp -m string 'prensalibre.com' --algo kmp -j ACCEPT) but is not working.

Comment: maybe a blacklist might be ok but a whitelist has an issue.. an expert I spoke to pointed out.. One wonders how you're handling things like DHCP, NTP, and OS updates if you're "only" allowing traffic to a single IP

Comment: dhcp and dns are handle by the server

Comment: @pamchi  so the computer running iptables, is that some kind of proxy to your gateway (so that local connections like DNS don't go through it but remote ones do)?

Comment: @barlop  RELATED,ESTABLISHED needs to be first.  If it is after DROP it will not do anything.

Comment: Rules will still be needed to allow DNS and DHCP and the gateway.

Comment: @cybernard surely you can specify a policy of drop, then a rule to accept. It's not saying drop all input then accept some. If anything it applies the rules then the policy afterwards.   It's ok to specify the policy of the chain before any of the rules  - even if the policy is drop it's still ok 'cos. It won't apply it at the start.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iptables  "3. the end of the chain is reached; traversal either continues in the parent chain (as if RETURN was used), or the base chain policy, which is an ultimate fate, is used."

Comment: @barlop  whoops I missed that it was a policy and note a rule. Sorry.

Comment: @cybernard re him saying DNS and DHCP are handled by his server. I'm no expert, but what if the traffic only passes through the proxy when it is destined for the gateway. And when it's DNS and DHCP it doesn't go through the proxy. I don't know if that's possible, but since he says "dhcp and dns are handle by the server" it sounds like he is saying he thinks the proxy has nothing to do with it. You are probably right though that he has DNS and DHCP going through his proxy too

Comment: All traffic still goes through iptables regardless of proxy or not.  Although your rules only block TCP, DNS sometimes uses TCP so sometime DNS will work sometimes it will be broken.  In addition you have not permitted access to his proxy's IP via TCP so accessing the proxy will also fail via TCP.  Also the gateway's IP is not listed so that will also be blocked if it is TCP traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d somewebsite.com --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

This will permit DNS and access to the specified domain. If you want to get rid of the DNS entry (--dport 53) all you have to do is add an entry for the site to your /etc/hosts file. I almost gave up on this till I saw conntrack in the comments.

Just permit additional sites just duplicate the site line and adjust accordingly. Keep them all above the DROPs.

You may also find one of my previous iptables related answers useful in your work. [need iptables rule to accept all incoming traffic](https://superuser.com/questions/634469/need-iptables-rule-to-accept-all-incoming-traffic/634471#634471)

Enjoy

Comment: i'm no expert but how about when DNS is TCP? so -p tcp --dport 53? And how about DHCP?

Comment: Then add the necessary rules. This answer provides the how-to of the question plus a DNS example. Anything else can be added as necessary.

Comment: If you're dropping DHCP then the computer might not even get a network connection. And if you haven't done DNS properly then sometimes DNS isn't going to work so even your DNS example isn't really right.

Comment: You write  "Just permit additional sites just duplicate the site line and adjust accordingly. Keep them all above the DROPs."  <--   The only drops there are the policies.. Why do you say it's important to have the policies last rather than first?   If you put the Policy first it's not going to make the rules not get accepted.

Comment: Cybernard has this comment which was maybe meant for your answer "DNS sometimes uses TCP so sometime DNS will work sometimes it will be broken. In addition you have not permitted access to his proxy's IP via TCP so accessing the proxy will also fail via TCP. Also the gateway's IP is not listed so that will also be blocked if it is TCP traffic. "